# How can I get the ID from an combobox filled with SQL data in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, combobox

I made a app where you can input items into the food database. One of the input fields is **types**. This is a separate table, and the combobox used to select the food type is filled with this table. This is what the tables look like:

**types**

```
---------------------
| id (PK) | name    |
---------------------
| int     | varchar |
---------------------
```

**foods**

```
-------------------------------------------------
| fid (PK) | fname   | typeid (FK:id) | price   |
-------------------------------------------------
| int      | varchar | int            | decimal |   
-------------------------------------------------
```

This is the code filling the combobox (TypeCB is the name of the combobox):

```
TypeCB.ItemsSource = db.types.ToList();
```

This is the code that doesnt work:

```
Food theFood = new Food();
Type theType = new Type();
theFood.name = NameText.Text;
theFood.typeid = Convert.ToInt32(TypeCB.SelectedValue);
theFood.price = Decimal.Parse(PriceText.Text);

db.Voers.InsertOnSubmit(hetVoer);
db.SubmitChanges();
```

What am I doing wrong here?
I get the error at:

```
theFood.typeid = Convert.ToInt32(TypeCB.SelectedValue);
```

Error:

System.InvalidCastException: 'Cant convert object WpfApp1.type to the type System.IConvertible.'

Comment: i provided the error

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have not specified the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` properties. Try specifying those and see if that helps like:

```
TypeCB.ItemsSource = db.types.ToList();
TypeCB.ValueMember= "id";
TypeCB.DisplayMember = "name";
```

I am not sure without specifying that what would the value coming in the `SelectedValue` property, probably the complete object of `type` instance.

Otherwise use `SelectedItem` as work around:

```
Type objType = TypeCB.SelectedItem;
theFood.typeid  = objtype.id;
```

assuming that `type` class has `fid` property holding the id.